# How can I know all the DDL that fired on an Oracle table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in my DB, let's say `tablea`. I want to know all the DDL statements that fired on that table.

If I query `user_objects` I can get the last time when a DDL fired on `tablea`, but not every single one.

By querying which table can I get that information?

Answer (score 0):

Table to query is sys.aud$ if only database auditing is properly set up.